# Create download link in cakephp 2.x inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have to create dynamic html download link but the filename and folder name I am getting in the jquery section. So how can I pass the $id and $filename from jquery to input field or is there any other way directly in jquery to create dynamic html link with cakephp.?

```
      <td class="broucher">
      </td>
```

I was trying to Jquery for that but it's not working and getting unexpected identifier error.

```
 var html='';
 var filename=ui.item.brouchersFile;
 var id=ui.item.brouchersId;
 html = '<?php echo $this->Html->Link("",array("controller"=> "download","action"=>"brochures",${id},${filename}),array("class"=>"fa fa-download fa-fw","download"=>${filename},"title"=>"Download"));  ?>' ;
 $(elmt).find(".broucher").append("<span class='msgspan'>${html}</span>");
```

Comment: When the PHP code runs on your server, `$id` and `$filename` are not defined. And when the JavaScript code runs on the browser, PHP is not available. You'll need to write JavaScript code that builds your link.

Answer (score 0):

You can define hidden field to access base url and then use the same in jquery to created the link for your desired action.

```
$this->Form->input('webroot', ['type' => 'hidden', 'id' => 'webroot', value=>$this->request->webroot]);
```

and then use that in your jquery like below

```
 var html='';
 var filename=ui.item.brouchersFile;
 var id=ui.item.brouchersId;
 var webroot= $("#webroot").val();
 html = '<a href="'+webroot+'/download/brochures/'+id+'/'+filename+'" class="fa fa-download fa-fw" download>Download</a>';
 $(elmt).find(".broucher").append("<span class='msgspan'>"+html+"</span>");
```